# curl max-time and connect-timeout not working at all

Tags: linux, curl

I am running curl 7.68.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.68.0 and I am trying to set **--max-time** or 
**--connect-timeout**, unfortunately these values seem to do nothing.

PoC 1:

```
time curl -v -k -I --max-time 5 https://myawesomehost/file.test
* Resolving timed out after 5001 milliseconds
* Closing connection 0
curl: (28) Resolving timed out after 5001 milliseconds

real    0m10.031s
user    0m0.011s
sys 0m0.012s
```

This should have killed the command after 5 seconds but it took 10.031s

PoC 2:

```
time curl -v -k -I --connect-timeout 3.0 https://myawesomehost/file.test
* Resolving timed out after 3000 milliseconds
* Closing connection 0
curl: (28) Resolving timed out after 3000 milliseconds

real    0m10.068s
user    0m0.005s
sys 0m0.010s
```

Again, it took 10.068s.

I found that I can use **timeout** command-line tool but I would like to know what is the issue with curl.

Comment: **Where did you get this copy of cURL?** Based on @anthony-t's comment below, it sounds like something's screwy with the way it was built, but it would probably be _good_ to hunt that to its source...

Answer (score 4):

Without seeing your `curl --version` let me take a stab in the dark based on just running into this exact problem.  Is your version of curl built without c-ares?  The first line of `curl --version` should tell you:

```
curl 7.71.0-DEV (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.71.0-DEV c-ares/1.10.0
```

I recently ran into this same issue where DNS timeouts caused curl to exceed the specified timeouts.  With verbose turned on it would show the DNS lookup DID timeout at 5 seconds, but then would wait until 20s to completely timeout and close.  We root caused it to versions without [c-ares](https://c-ares.haxx.se/) (asynchronous DNS resolver library).

I built it from source taken from their [github](https://github.com/curl/curl) using these [instructions](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/GIT-INFO) but adding `./configure --enable-ares`

Here you can see it built with c-ares `c-ares/1.10.0` in the version info

```
$ /usr/local/bin/curl --version
curl 7.71.0-DEV (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.71.0-DEV c-ares/1.10.0
Release-Date: [unreleased]
Protocols: dict file ftp gopher http imap pop3 rtsp smtp telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile UnixSockets
```

and it behaves as expected

```
$ time /usr/local/bin/curl --max-time 5 google.com -v
* Resolving timed out after 5000 milliseconds
* Closing connection 0
curl: (28) Resolving timed out after 5000 milliseconds

real    0m5.002s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.002s
```

And built without c-ares

```
/usr/local/bin/curl --version
curl 7.71.0-DEV (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.71.0-DEV
Release-Date: [unreleased]
Protocols: dict file ftp gopher http imap pop3 rtsp smtp telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile UnixSockets
```

Timeout doesn't work:

```
time /usr/local/bin/curl --max-time 5 google.com -v
* Resolving timed out after 5000 milliseconds
* Closing connection 0
curl: (28) Resolving timed out after 5000 milliseconds

real    0m20.023s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.000s
```

If you're building curl from source or it's an option for you likely just need to enable that option.

Edit:
JamesTheAwesomeDude made an excellent point that chasing down where this cURL came from is worth figuring out.  In my case it was a fresh EC2 instance running Amazon Linux 2.

```
$ cat /etc/*-release | grep PRETTY_NAME
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
```

Comment: I had the exact same issue, built it from source with the given instructions - it said c-ares was enabled when configuring and `libc-ares-dev` is installed. But after installing, running `curl -V` doesn't mention c-ares at all and it doesn't work :/

Comment: `--max-time` works perfect on freebsd